# Receiving money from a foreign source as payment for a domestic service

Tags: india, real-estate, international-transfer, contractor

I wish to act as an agent to purchase land for a foreigner-owned company.  To meet my initial expenses, the company is prepared to send me money.

1. Are there restrictions on the methods by which I can receive money from them?
2. Is there a maximum amount I can receive from them?
3. Must I receive/prepare/retain any documentation for such a transaction?  If so, what?

I wish to follow all legal formalities, rules and regulations relating to financial transactions as well as income tax etc in our country (India).

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to act as an agent to purchase land for a foreigner-owned company.

Have you done enough due diligence on the company and know this company ... it could be a scam.

> Are there restrictions on the methods by which I can receive money from them?

Any Banking Channel would be good.

> Is there a maximum amount I can receive from them?

For inflow of funds, there is no restriction.

> Must I receive/prepare/retain any documentation for such a transaction? If so, what?

Yes. You would need to declare this as your income in India and pay taxes accordingly. Having a contract specifying that you are doing consulting would help.

Further how the final sale is being structured, it would make sense that payment from the foreign company be directly sent to buyer. There are compliance normal regarding deducting a portion of taxes and paying this to Income tax and remaining to Seller. It is advisable to have a CA who would help you / the foreign company with the formalities.